# Unity Failed to call Unity ID to get auth code

Tags: unity3d-editor

Whenever I try to import assets using the Package Manager it fails to load.

[image: here is a screenshot]

Here is the full error:

> [Package Manager Window] Error while getting auth code:
> System.InvalidOperationException: Failed to call Unity ID to get auth
> code. UnityEditor.AsyncHTTPClient:Done
> (UnityEditor.AsyncHTTPClient/State,int)

I tried some YouTube tutorials but they did not work for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzaFy.png)

I ran into the same problem, but I solved it by signing in from the red frame.

Comment: For anyone who couldn't find the red frame, there's a small red frame in the top left side of the picture in the link.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are logged in unity with the same unity assets store  account you want to import assets from .

the log in button location in unity 2021.3.6f1
[e.g.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4J3OR.png)

the log in button location in unity 2019.2.6f1
[e.g.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMmf9.png)

Comment: No, the Async HTTP Client have the state Done

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve this problem in windows (my Unity version is 2021.3.17f)
sign out from Unity Hub ten close the browser and project then sign in again if it doesn't work for you, try to turn off firewall in Windows then try again these steps it should work our errors are the same.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is facing the same issue on a company network, try to turn off the proxy in the Windows settings. Then restart the Unity Hub and the Unity Editor.[image]